# Pandas limit the number of rows per class

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a pandas DataFrame with columns index, className, filePath.

Each row is a different image file. I want to limit the max number of each class allowed in:

```
print(df[["className"]].value_counts())

class A              208336
class B              196264
class C              189197
class D              186476
class E              139782
                        ...  
class F                1003
class G                1002
class H                1002
class I                1001
class J                1000
```

Then apply function to limit to 5000 per class

```
print(df[["className"]].value_counts())

class A                5000
class B                5000
class C                5000
class D                5000
class E                5000
                        ...  
class F                1003
class G                1002
class H                1002
class I                1001
class J                1000
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use `groupby` then `head`. Consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"cls":["A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C"],"y":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
df2 = df.groupby("cls").head(3)
print(df2)
```

output

```
  cls  y
0   A  1
1   A  2
2   A  3
5   B  6
6   B  7
7   B  8
8   C  9
```

Above code selects three or all (whatever is greater) records for given `cls`.

Comment: Absolutely right